# Monitoring Instant Messages in GTalk with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, instant-messaging

How can I monitor instant messages received on gtalk using .NET? Basically, I need to run a program upon receiving the arguments as instant message from a particular google id and pass the result back to the sender. Is it possible to do it?

EDIT: I can have gtalk running on both machines (sort of client and server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GTalk uses the [XMPP protocol](http://www.xmpp.org/) under the hood and there are a few libraries around in .NET for XMPP.

There is also an article [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=346) that gives you examples using one such library ([agsXMPP](http://www.ag-software.de/index.php?page=agsxmpp-sdk)) to do auto-replies on GTalk.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the link! agsXMPP needs some documentation :D

Answer (score 2):

try with this [link](http://gtalkautoreply.codeplex.com/)  This says that how to do Automatic reply .Hope this will help you to the next level of your work.It is coordinated with [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) server  .This is only for gtalk .Not for yahoo